# How to display nodes returned from nw:bicomponent-clusters

Tags: netlogo

I want to display nodes stored in clusters on screen.

```
 let clusters nw:bicomponent-clusters 
 print clusters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will color all the nodes returned by let clusters nw:bicomponent-clusters

```
   let clusters nw:bicomponent-clusters 
   foreach clusters 
      [ set color pink]
```